# SQL Server like Statement add getdate + wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I want to replace the `like` statement with this function

```
select year(GetDate()) and add '%'
```

Can you help me how to do it?

Here is the SQL statement:

```
Select *
from table a 
where = month like '2023%'
```

I expect same result like the SQL statement, but replace with `year(getdate())` statement.

Comment: Don't use `%` on date. Use `>=` and `<` instead. Example : `WHERE DateColumn >= '20230101' and DateColumn < '20240101'`

Comment: Don't treat date (and time) values like a string, they are *not* a string. Treat them as what they *are*, a date and time value. This means that if you want rows for a particular year, you need to use a *range* in the `WHERE` clause, like @Squirrel has shown you. Similar to if you wanted rows where a `int` value was in the 100's you would might do `WHERE IntValue >= 100 AND IntValue < 200`. You *wouldn't* do `WHERE IntValue LIKE '1__'`

Comment: Also - `2023` is most **likely** the **YEAR** - not the month ....

Comment: As others have already stated, there are no wildcards with dates.  You search on a range using the date datatype.  For a list of SQL functions that work with date refer to the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure whether string comparison makes sense in this case.
Nevertheless, I think you're looking for something like this (Convert to nvarchar and append %):

```
convert(nvarchar(4),year(GetDate())) +'%'
```

Full query:

```
Select *
from table a 
where month like convert(nvarchar(4),year(GetDate())) +'%'
```